# can I use same return value for function loops in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit confused with the return values of the function. I have a form and there are text boxes and radio buttons in that. I am validating all the text boxes together and radio buttons together. So I have now 2 return values from these 2 function. Can I use same return variable for these 2 function.
This is my code

```
$(function() {
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    var returnValue = true;
    //Validating radio buttons required
    //Code of checking radio buttons
        if( !unchecked.is(':checked') ) {
            alert("Required field");
            returnValue = false;
        }
    });

    //Other Required fields

    $('.required_text').filter(':visible').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            alert("Required field");
            returnValue = false;
        }
    });
    alert(returnValue);
    return returnValue;
});

}
});
```

If I use different return variables for each of these function like radioReturn and textReturn and in the last if I use

```
if(radioReturn && textReturn){
returnValue = true;
}
else{
returnValue = false;
}
```

But I dont want to use too many variables. So is there any way where I can use only one return variable and handle the form submit.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Also the generic `alert("required field")` tells the user nothing about what field it is!

Comment: @epascarello..Yes I tried it..This is just the sample of my code..Actual code tells the user the the field details..I just wanted to know if I can use on one return variable for different functions and then submit the form based on that return

Comment: Yes, there is no rule that you can not use one variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can

Try like this

```
$(function() {
    // all validation inside the click event
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
      // initiate the value as true
      var returnValue = true;
      //Validating radio buttons required
      //Code of checking radio buttons
      if( !unchecked.is(':checked') ) {
        alert("Required field");
        // add css to highlight error
        returnValue = false;
      }
      // check the input fields only if returnValue is true
      // if u want to highlight  all the errors then this check no need
      if(returnValue)
      {
        $('.required_text').filter(':visible').each(function () {
           var input = $(this);
           if (!$(this).val()) {
              // add css to highlight error
              alert("Required field");
           returnValue = false;
           }
         });
      }
      //Other Required fields

      alert(returnValue);
      return returnValue;
});


});
```

UPDATE 2:

```
  $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
       // initiate the value as true
       var returnValue = true;


       //Validating radio buttons required
       //Code of checking radio buttons
       if( !unchecked.is(':checked') ) {             
         // add css to highlight error or
         // add label nearby it to said Required
         returnValue = false;
        }

        // check the input fields only if returnValue is true
        // if u want to highlight  all the errors then this check no need
        $('.required_text').filter(':visible').each(function () {
          var input = $(this);
          if (!$(this).val()) {
             // add css to highlight error or
             // add label nearby it to said Required
           returnValue = false;
        }
      });

      //Other Required fields

      // here if u have any errors then the return value always false
      alert(returnValue);
      return returnValue;
  });
```

Comment: Hi Gowsikan..Yes, I need to highlight all the errors. So is there anyway I can check that?